# Angular: Accessing nested properties in controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, controller, nested

I'm new to **Angular** and I'm having some trouble accessing object properties in my controller. I have an array that I'm able to access in my controller (which was returned from the back-end of my application), and that array contains a single object with properties that I'd like to access. I'm trying to figure out how exactly to access those properties (on the object contained in the array).

I've tried using the `angular.forEach()` method (although this feels like a hacky approach) but still can't get at the properties nested two levels deep.

Here's how my console represents the `array`, the `object`, and its `properties`:

```
[Object]   0: Object
    __v: 0
    _id: "55a054808af99da01701ab60"
    hex_color_code: "#B79152"
    name: "camel"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1   __proto__: Array[0]
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you are using mongo database, but didn't expose model population, check your server side controller, generally its **exports.list** method. Then check mongodb *populate* function. Or just copy some functionality from **exports.[controller_name]ById**